# Merge two functions?

Tags: javascript

Say, I have two functions:

```
function foo() {
  this.lorem = 'ipsum';
}

function boo() {
  console.log(this.lorem);
}
```

And I want to insert the `boo` function at the end of the `foo` function so that they can share the same `this`. How would I do it?

Comment: I don't think you understand what `this` actually refers to. It refers to the `window` object. You are making `lorem` global. There is no "sharing" of `this` involved. In both functions `this` already refers to the same object (`window`). Even `foo(); console.log(this.lorem);` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
function foo() {
    this.lorem = 'ipsum';
    console.log(this.lorem);
}
```

In all seriousness, your question is not clear enough to be reliably answered.

Answer (score 1):

In the event you want to keep them separate:

```
function foo() {
  this.lorem = 'ipsum';
  boo(this);
}

function boo(element) {
  console.log(element.lorem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them both under the same context:

```
var myClass = {
    foo: function foo() {
        this.lorem = 'ipsum';
        this.boo();
    }, boo: function boo() {
        alert(this.lorem);
    }
};
```

Then to activate `foo`:

```
myClass.foo();
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/BPjBU/).

Comment: That's not a class, that's an object.

Comment: I think you meant `foo: function() { … }` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo() {
  this.lorem = 'ipsum';
  boo.call(this);
}

function boo() {
  console.log(this.lorem);
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the existing functions do this:

```
function foo() {
  this.lorem = 'ipsum';
}

function boo() {
  console.log(this.lorem);
}


function bar() {
    boo.call(new foo);
}

bar();
```

Here's a JSFiddle of it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Wb6T/