# JavaScript: How to merge two functions into one new function?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge two functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091650/merge-two-functions)

Say, I have these two functions:

```
function foo() {
  this.lorem = 'ipsum';
}

function boo() {
  console.log(this.lorem);
}
```

And I want to merge them into one, say, `fb` function.

So, triggering the `fb` function will display the `lorem` word in the console.

It needs to be done without modifying the two functions.

Comment: Deja-vu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091650/merge-two-functions

Comment: This is a sockpuppet account.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {
  this.lorem = 'ipsum';
}

function boo() {
  console.log(this.lorem);
}


function bar() {
    boo.call(new foo);
}

bar();
```

Here's a JSFiddle of it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Wb6T/

Answer (score -1):

I dont really see what good this would do, but you ca create a third function that runs the 2 existing functions:

```
function foo() {
  this.lorem = 'ipsum';
}

function boo() {
  console.log(this.lorem);
}

function fb () {
  foo();
  bar();
}
```